# 415 exception Cherrypy webservice

Tags: python, ajax, cross-domain, cherrypy

I'm trying to build a Cherrypy/Python webservice. I already spend the whole day on finding out how to make a cross domain ajax request possible. That's finally working, but now I have the next issue. I think I already know the solution, but I don't know how to implement it. The problem is that when I'm sending the ajax request, the Cherrypy server responds with:

```
415 Unsupported Media Type

Expected an entity of content type application/json, text/javascript

Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 663, in respond    self.body.process()  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpreqbody.py", line 996, in process    super(RequestBody, self).process()  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpreqbody.py", line 538, in process    self.default_proc()  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cperror.py", line 411, in __call__    raise selfHTTPError: (415, u'Expected an entity of content type application/json, text/javascript')
```

The solution I found, and trying to test, is adding this line to the configuration:

```
'tools.json_in.force': False
```

So I tried to implement it in this code:

```
import cherrypy
import json
import sys

class RelatedDocuments:

def index(self):
    return "Hello World!"

@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
def findRelated(self, **raw):
    #Get JSON message form request
    request = cherrypy.request.json
    result = []

    #SOME CODE...

    return result;

# Expose the index method through the web. CherryPy will never
# publish methods that don't have the exposed attribute set to True.
index.exposed = True
findRelated.exposed = True

def CORS():
    cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"

import os.path
tutconf = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'webserver.conf')
config = {
    'global': {
        'server.socket_host':'127.0.0.1',
        'server.socket_port': 8080,
        'log.error_file' : 'Web.log',
        'log.access_file' : 'Access.log'
    },
    '/': {
        'tools.CORS.on': True
    }
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.tools.CORS = cherrypy.Tool('before_finalize', CORS)

    cherrypy.quickstart(RelatedDocuments(),config=config)
```

I added the config line under the tools.CORS.on line, but that didn't work. Next i tried this:

```
cherrypy.config.update({
    'tools.json_in.force': False,
});
```

Didn't work eiter..next I tried to implement this right above the findRelated method:

```
@cherrypy.config(**{'tools.json_in.force': False})
```

All of the implementations gave me a 500 error, I really appreciate it if somebody can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've realised that the question is in fact about [*CORS preflight request*](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0). CORS [specification defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-method) the following condition for a simple CORS request:

- Method: `GET`, `HEAD`, `POST`
- Headers: `Accept`, `Accept-Language`, `Content-Language`, `Content-Type`
- Cotent-type header value: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, `text/plain`

Otherwise CORS request isn't simple, and use preflight OPTIONS request before actual request to ensure it's eligible. Here is [good CORS how-to](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

So if you want to keep things simple you may want to revert to normal `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Otherwise you need to handle preflight requests correctly. Here's working example (don't forget to add `localhost` alias).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Add localhost alias, `proxy` , in /etc/hosts.
'''


import cherrypy


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  }
}


def cors():
  if cherrypy.request.method == 'OPTIONS':
    # preflign request 
    # see http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0
    cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST'
    cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'content-type'
    cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']  = '*'
    # tell CherryPy no avoid normal handler
    return True
  else:
    cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

cherrypy.tools.cors = cherrypy._cptools.HandlerTool(cors)


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'>
      <title>CORS AJAX JSON request</title>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
          $('button').on('click', function()
          {
            $.ajax({
              'type'        : 'POST',
              'dataType'    : 'JSON',
              'contentType' : 'application/json',
              'url'         : 'http://proxy:8080/endpoint',
              'data'        : JSON.stringify({'foo': 'bar'}),
              'success'     : function(response)
              {
                console.log(response);  
              }
            });
          })
        });
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <button>make request</button>
      </body>
      </html>
    '''

  @cherrypy.expose
  @cherrypy.config(**{'tools.cors.on': True})
  @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
  @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
  def endpoint(self):
    data = cherrypy.request.json
    return data.items()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you've made my day! Everything is working fine now, never even heard about the preflight request.

Answer (score 3):

In general if you have chosen a tool, then you're better using it, instead of fighting it. CherryPy tells you that for JSON input it expects request with `application/json` or `text/javascript` content-type.

Here's code of [`cherrypy.lib.jsontools.json_in`](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/52529f8fca772db5eae4d749ab3e082e5ec8ece0/cherrypy/lib/jsontools.py?at=default#cl-43):

```
def json_in(content_type=[ntou('application/json'), ntou('text/javascript')],
            force=True, debug=False, processor=json_processor):

    request = cherrypy.serving.request
    if isinstance(content_type, basestring):
        content_type = [content_type]

    if force:
        if debug:
            cherrypy.log('Removing body processors %s' %
                         repr(request.body.processors.keys()), 'TOOLS.JSON_IN')
        request.body.processors.clear()
        request.body.default_proc = cherrypy.HTTPError(
            415, 'Expected an entity of content type %s' %
            ', '.join(content_type))

    for ct in content_type:
        if debug:
            cherrypy.log('Adding body processor for %s' % ct, 'TOOLS.JSON_IN')
        request.body.processors[ct] = processor
```

`force` doesn't do anything more than removing existing body processors. If you set `force` to `False`, then you need to tell CherryPy how to treat the request body you send to it.

Or, better, use CherryPy and tell it correct content-type. With jQuery it's as simple as:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    'type'        : 'POST',
    'dataType'    : 'JSON',
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
    'url'         : '/findRelated',
    'data'        : JSON.stringify({'foo': 'bar'})
 });
```

Comment: Yeah I know...I had already seen this file and my contentType was application/json in the first place. But then my HTTP request changed from a POST to an OPTIONS method, but I explicitly set the method to be POST. I found some info about this, and it is probably something with cross domain ajax request to, but couldn't find a solution. I'm just trying to setup a quick prototype, so I found the other solution and hoped I could just quick fix this for the time being.