# How to cross-domain in cherrypy normal application?

Tags: python, cross-domain, cherrypy

```
class HelloWorld:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def hello(self):
        return "Hello World!"
```

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())

I do cross-domain request： http://ip:port/hello unsuccessfully, and then I add a decorator(which is working successfully  in my restful application) before method hello like that:

```
def crossdomain(func):
    def decorate(*args, **kwargs):
        cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE"
        allow_headers = ["Cache-Control", "X-Proxy-Authorization", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type"]
        cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = ",".join(allow_headers)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorate

class HelloWorld:
    @cherrypy.expose
    @crossdomain
    def hello(self):
        return "Hello World!"

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

the browser throw this exception:
OPTIONS http://192.168.1.236:1987/hello 500 (Internal Server Error)

because the cherrypy can not find the http method "OPTIONS".
but how can I make cherrypy dispatch the OPTIONS request automatically？

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of the preflight issue [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28049898/2072035). Did you search before asking the question?