# Sending JSON string to cherrypy

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, cherrypy

I'm trying to send a JSON string from a single HTML (this file is not served by cherrypy) file via Javascript to a cherrpy server.

This is my minimal cherrypy example ([followed the "dealing with json" part](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html?highlight=json#dealing-with-json))

```
import cherrypy

class HelloJson(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    def default(self):
        data = cherrypy.request.json
        print(data)
        return "Hello world!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port':1234})
    cherrypy.quickstart(HelloJson())
```

Sending a JSON string via python works gently

```
>>> requests.post('http://localhost:1234', json=json.dumps({'Hello': 'Json'}))
<Response [200]>
>>>
```

The cherrypy output prints the json string too

```
20:59 $ ./HelloJson.py 
[24/Aug/2015:20:59:34] ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM.
[24/Aug/2015:20:59:34] ENGINE Listening for SIGUSR1.
[24/Aug/2015:20:59:34] ENGINE Listening for SIGHUP.
[24/Aug/2015:20:59:34] ENGINE Bus STARTING
CherryPy Checker:
The Application mounted at '' has an empty config.

[24/Aug/2015:20:59:34] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[24/Aug/2015:20:59:34] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[24/Aug/2015:20:59:34] ENGINE Serving on http://127.0.0.1:1234
[24/Aug/2015:20:59:34] ENGINE Bus STARTED
{"Hello": "Json"}
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2015:21:00:17] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "" "python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/3.4.3 Linux/4.1.5-1-ARCH"
```

So my single HTML file looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function makeRequest()
{
    var insertJSON = { "my_key": "my_value" };

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:1234");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(insertJSON));

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frm1" id="yourTextBox" onsubmit="makeRequest()">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But this results in an error `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'json'`

```
[24/Aug/2015:21:10:36] HTTP 
Request Headers:
  CONNECTION: keep-alive
  ACCEPT-LANGUAGE: en-US,en;q=0.5
  ACCESS-CONTROL-REQUEST-HEADERS: content-type
  ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  USER-AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
  ACCESS-CONTROL-REQUEST-METHOD: POST
  ACCEPT-ENCODING: gzip, deflate
  PRAGMA: no-cache
  CACHE-CONTROL: no-cache
  HOST: localhost:1234
  Remote-Addr: 127.0.0.1
  ORIGIN: null
[24/Aug/2015:21:10:36] HTTP Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 670, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 217, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 61, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "./HelloJson.py", line 15, in default
    data = cherrypy.request.json
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cherrypy/__init__.py", line 224, in __getattr__
    return getattr(child, name)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'json'

127.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2015:21:10:36] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 500 1515 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
```

I've no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *OPTIONS* request you see is a [*CORS preflight request*](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0), which obviously isn't a JSON request and you see the error. Because you open your file from `file://` protocol (or another host), and *CherryPy* is serving on `http://127.0.0.1:1234` you do a cross-domain request, which is subject to [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

The simplest way to solve this is to also serve the HTML file by CherryPy ([Static content serving](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html#static-content-serving)). The hard way is to provide proper CORS headers to allow cross domain requests (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28065698/2072035))

Answer (score 0):

I agree with saaj's response that the browser sends a CORS preflight request which can be handled in the following manner:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloJson(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    def POST(self):
        data = cherrypy.request.json
        print(data)
        return "Hello world!"

    def OPTIONS(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, OPTIONS"
        cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = "true"
        cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = "86400"
        cherrypy.response.headers[
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "X-Mobile, Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
        cherrypy.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        return ''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update({
            'server.socket_port':1234, 
            'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()
    })
    cherrypy.quickstart(HelloJson(), '/')
```

This would work because now you have enabled your API backend to listen to browser's OPTIONS call which tells the browser, what are the allowed methods and origins. `cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()` enables you to treat your class as a method dispatcher and thus you can use the class to serve RESTFUL API.